# SQL Server Stored Procedure into Java using Hibernate

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, stored-procedures, java-stored-procedures

Please, could anyone help me on this below stuff?

I have a stored Procedure which has business logic that i need to convert into Java using Hibernate as per customer requirement.

And also i know Stored procedure will help us to improve the performance but for customer need, we are doing this, to convert our application into a Product.

In my Stored Procedure it has lot of temp tables involved with lot of Joins with actual physical tables(which has more than 50000 records), So now i am trying to have so many list to have the data which has in a temp table and iterate from a list, i am sure it will affect performance.

Could you please let me know anyway that i can achieve all those steps involved in that Stored Procedure needs to convert into Java.

Stored Procedure is in SQL Server, later will have the plan to migrate to Oracle , i couldn't use any Native SQL here.

Comment: It's hard to help without more details...we have no idea what your query is actually doing.

Comment: Please provide the query then also the code that you have tried so far...